# Superimpose a transparent PNG on a GIF animation

Tags: imagemagick, png, gif, image-manipulation, animated-gif

I want to add watermark images to GIF animations with ImageMagick.

The following doesn't work: it just gives produces a weird single image with crazy colors, and the transparent-watermark.png doesn't seem to be there at all.

```
composite -compose Dst_Over background-gif.gif transparent-watermark.png final.gif
```

How can this be accomplished? It's similar to [annotating](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#annotating) but with an image instead of text.

Comment: The problem is that GIF images can only contain 256 colors, specified by a palette within the image. If the PNG has a different palette, or worse is 24 bit without a palette, combining them is a difficult process that might not give acceptable results.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert background-animation.gif -coalesce -gravity NorthEast -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "transparent-watermark.png"' -layers Optimize final.gif
```

Comment: Useful for creating Elgato Stream Deck animated icons, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had same problem with

```
convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png animated.gif
```

And fix it adding -alpha remove

```
convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png -alpha remove animated.gif
```

Try **-alpha remove** or **-background white**(other cases) to fix it.

Comment: I use both the -alpha remove and -background white